# Element class in Haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I am using Haml in a Ruby on Rails project. I know you use the = sign to execute Ruby, but so far what I have seen is that the Ruby code has to be the last part of a line.

I am trying to add a class to a `th` element dynamically. (In case it's relevant: each `td` also contains more Ruby.)

I have the following code:

```
%th= link_to 'Name', res_path
```

I want to add a class to `th`, and the name of this class is in an instance variable called `class_name`. I tried this:

```
%th.=@class_name
```

But it doesn't work.

How should one include Ruby code twice on the same line using Haml?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The html_options solution offered by Alok will add the class to the 'a' tag. I would do this over two lines instead of one:

```
%th{ :class => @class_name }
  = link_to 'Name', res_path
```

Answer (score 2):

As @DavB pointed out, only static text can be used with the `.`/`#` notation. Otherwise, you can either pass your options to your helper method (if it accepts them), or, more universally, use a hash attribute as in `%th{:class => @name}`. It will result in `<th class="namevalue">`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`html_options`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) of the `link_to` tag and then add the class there. I think thats the standard way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks, but that adds the class to 'a' not 'th'